# Find longest subsequence in an array

Tags: python

The problem here is to find the length of **longest subsequence** from the input array such that all the elements are in sorted order.

**Example: input** => `[10,22,9,33,21,50,41,60,80]`

**Example: Output** => `[10,22,33,50,60,80]` is **6**

My attempt:

```
def longest_sequence(input):
    obj = []
    for x in sorted(input):
        obj.append(x)
    print[obj, len(obj)]
    # [[9, 10, 21, 22, 33, 41, 50, 60, 80], 9]

longest_sequence([10,22,9,33,21,50,41,60,80])
```

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) has an article on the problem, including an efficient algorithm to solve it. It might be difficult to understand the explanation, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
import bisect

def lis(xs):
    ret = []
    for x in xs:
        i = bisect.bisect_left(ret, x)
        ret[i:i+1] = x,
    return len(ret)
```

Example:

```
>>> lis([10, 1, 2, 3])
3
>>> lis([10,22,9,33,21,50,41,60,80])
6
```

**NOTE** In the above code,`ret` does not contains valid subsequence. But the length is correct. **Use the above code what you want is only the length of the LIS**.

Explanation:

Think about `[10,22,9,11]`. There could be two LIS: `[10,22]`, `[9,11]`. The `ret` in the above `lis` function maintains the following condition:

- `ret` is sorted; can use binary search (bisect.bisect_left)
- `ret[i]` contains the minimum last value for length-`i` subsequence.
- `ret` changes as... (given `[10,22,9,11]` as  input)

  - [10]    - after processing the 1st element
  - [10, 22] - after processing the 2nd element
  - [9, 22] - ...  **Now the minimum value for 1-length subsequence is 9! 10 is overwritten.**
  - [9, 11]

Time complexity: O(nk) where n is the number of list item, k is the length of the LIS.

**UPDATE**

Modified version that correctly get the subsequence:

```
import bisect

def lis(xs):
    if not xs: return []
    prev = {}
    ret = []
    for x in xs:
        i = bisect.bisect_left(ret, x)
        ret[i:i+1] = x,
        prev[x] = ret[i-1] if i > 0 else None
    subseq = [ret[-1]]
    while subseq[-1] is not None:
        subseq.append(prev[subseq[-1]])
    return list(reversed(subseq[:-1]))
```

Example:

```
>>> lis([])
[]
>>> lis([10, 1, 2, 3])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> lis([10,22,9,33,21,50,41,60,80])
[10, 22, 33, 41, 60, 80]
>>> lis([1,5,2,6,3,4])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> lis([100,200,1,2,3])
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Doesn't work. `[9, 21, 33, 41, 60, 80]` isn't a subsequence of `[10,22,9,33,21,50,41,60,80]`; you're reordering the elements of the input, which isn't allowed.

Comment: Can you please add some comments about how this works?

Comment: @aIKid, I added an explanation. I wish that explain what the function does.

Answer (score -1):

```
data = [100,1,2,3]

conformed = []

for i in range (0, len(data)):
   if i == 0:
      if data[1]<data[0]:
         conformed.append(data[1])
      else:
         conformed.append(data[0])
   else:
       if data[i] > data[i-1]:
          conformed.append(data[i])

print conformed, len(conformed)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Try `[100, 1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: Indeed. Fixed. Clumsy, but fixed.

Comment: Not fixed. Try `[100, 200, 1, 2, 3]`.